# How do I implement a 'tracking' object inside of my class constructor?

Tags: javascript, performance, class, object, typeerror

I've built a Binary Sudoku web-app that utilizes a chain of recursive functions to generate a random solved grid, at which point the grid is cut down, by some reduction functions, to a few starting tiles for players to reassemble (solve). For the sake of my own curiosity, I am trying to build a constructor object inside of my main generator class that will keep track of how many times each recursive function is ran, each time I generate a new board (not interested in persisting this data past a single board instance). I would also like to log the total runtime of this operation after the board has been generated.

So far, I have attempted to implement this object inside of my constructor:

```
this.stats = {
        rowGenerator: 0,
        rowAssembler: 0,
        colTotalCheck: 0,
        colUniqueCheck: 0,
        runtime: 0
    };
```

Inside each of my four recursive functions, I've placed these increments at the top:

```
this.stats.rowGenerator++;
this.stats.rowAssembler++;
this.stats.colTotalCheck++;
this.stats.colUniqueCheck++;
```

Currently, this is returning a TypeError for each reference to respective 'stats' values.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'colUniqueCheck')
```

I've also placed timing methods before and after the recursive chain to log runtime, but unfortunately the only timing feedback I'm receiving back is '0ms'.
The timing methods are written as such:

```
startTime() {
    // before recursive chain
    return performance.now();
};
 endTime() {
    // after recursive chain
    return performance.now();
};
totalTime() {
    const end = this.endTime();
    const start = this.startTime();
    return `Runtime: ${end - start}ms`;
};
```

I've searched for similar problems but cannot find any useful information that is unique to these problems, perhaps tracking these trivial little stats is unrealistic inside of a class.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: It should work. There is something you are not showing, perhaps you lose your `this` binding at some point. Please post a full reproducible example showing the problem.

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) Find the first point in the execution where the state of the variables is not what you expect & say what you expect & why you expect it, justified by reference to authoritative documentation. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `this.checkColumnsUnique` (which accesses `this.stats`) before you even initialize `this.stats`:

```js
    this.fillBoard = this.checkColumnsUnique();
    this.stats = {
        rowGenerator: 0,
        rowAssembler: 0,
        colTotalCheck: 0,
        colUniqueCheck: 0,
        runtime: 0
    };
```

If you reverse the order of these two statements, it will work.

(There is one other issue though - in `checkColumnsUnique` you call `checkColumnsUnique` without `this.` in front.)